# cordova failed to ganarate apk saying there is somthing occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I'm a beginner in ionic ..  and am trying to generate the apk from an ionic project .. but unfortunately it failed to be generated giving me this error

```
 Android Studio project detected

 ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\abdel ysf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
 JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_151
 studio
 Subproject Path: CordovaLib
 Subproject Path: app
 publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All 
 variants are now published.
 [18:51:59]  lint finished in 15.14 s
 Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in 
 C:\Users\abdel ysf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
 Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not 
 accepted.

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
 > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following 
 SDK components:
 [Android SDK Platform 26].
 Before building your project, you need to accept the license 
 agreements and complete the installation of the missing 
 components 
 using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
```

The command I used is : ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Android Studio SDK Manager and under 'SDK platforms' tab, select the required Android versions(Ex:Android 8.1(Oreo)) and click OK. If the error keeps repeating, try installing some of the previous Android versions too.

Answer (score 2):

Open Android studio, open Android SDK manager. Accept License of SDK.

Comment: i have already accepted the license of sdk .. although it keeps showing ms the same error

Answer (score -1):

Find your own local android-sdk, if you download the relevant sdk of ndk, there will be a folder called "ndk-bundle"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RWrT.png)

There is a folder called "toolchains" inside.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ng6d.png)

We noticed that there are no mips64el related files inside.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u14Ay.png)

The solution is as follows:

Click [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/?hl=zh-en) to download the NDK package separately through the browser.
After unzipping, open the "toolchains" folder, compare it with the android-sdk->ndk-bundle->toolchains folder, find the missing folder, copy the past
3. Recompile, the problem is solved.
Hope it helps you mate